# Hasura - Actions for Authentication (Login, Logout, Register)

Tags: angular, graphql, hasura

I have a server running a Hasura and GraphQL. I need to implement an authentication system and I am trying to find the easiest but most stable and secure way to do it.

I found some examples online on how to use GraphQL actions to register a user by generating some code to run on a small node server. I was wondering if it is possible to run an entire authentication system this way.

It must be possible to login, logout, get a token with info about user type etc, refresh the token and validate it every page you visit and request you send.

I am a front end dev and I have never done this kind of things so any help would be great.
By the way, the front end is made with Angular + ngx-admin (no ngx-admin backend though)

Regards

Comment: I believe using 3rd party services like Auth0/Firebase is the good solution to go. My recommend is NEVER implement Authentication/Authorization by your hand.

Comment: I already have a working web app with a local db that includes all the user data and login info. I see that Auth0 requires the project to be in Hasura Cloud instead, so I don't know if this could work for me.

Comment: First, Hasura Cloud is definitely optional, I'm using open source version and it works fine.The thing is you need to let Firebase/Auth0 handles everything related to Authentication/Authorization. Please follow the official docs because it is kind of rebuild ALL the login flow.

Comment: ok I can try. First time doing this ahah. Can you link me the documentation or guide on how to use Auth0 without Hasura Cloud? Thank you very much. EDIT: btw, do you I can integrate this also in a mobile app easily?

Comment: This course is comprehensive enough: https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/hasura/introduction/